# Javascript: ERROR RangeError: Invalid time value

Tags: javascript

Below is my code.

```js
let a = "26-Jan-2021 06:02 PM PST";

let d = "27-Jan-2021 07:32 AM IST";

let b = new Date(a).toString();

let c = new Date(a).toISOString();

console.log(c);

let e = new Date(d).toISOString();

console.log(e);
```

OutPut:

```
"2021-01-27T02:02:00.000Z"

"Invalid time value"
```

Question: What is the difference between how JavaScript interprets variables a and d that it spits out such different outputs?

Comment: Try to use Markdown, so that your code will become readable.

Answer (score 4):

Creating a Date object from a date string parses formats recognized by [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14). While it accepts `PST` as a valid (although obsolete) timezone for "Pacific Standard Time", it doesn't accept `IST` as a valid timezone within the timestamp.

Instead, you'd want to replace `IST` with `GMT+0530` or `UTC+0530` (meaning Greenwich Mean Time / Coordinated Universal Time + 5h 30min, the definition for India Standard Time):

```js
let c = new Date("26-Jan-2021 06:02 PM GMT+0530").toISOString()
console.log(c) // => '2021-01-26T12:32:00.000Z'
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, the `new Date()` constructor for a timestamp string accepts IETF-Compliant RFC 2822 timestamps. [Page 31 of the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-32) lists the timezones that are acceptable. IST isn't one of them. Therefore, your date string is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

use `GMT+0530` instead of `IST` as IST is not identified as timezone in JS (not recognized by RFC-2822)

```
let dateSample = new Date("26-Jan-2021 06:02 PM GMT+0530").toISOString()
console.log(dateSample)
```

prints: 2021-01-26T12:32:00.000Z